# Multiple components scope conflict

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working on an admin panel application which is based on AngularJS 1.5. It is structured as follows:

1. There is a main component called `app`, in which I am using all other components.

**`app.html`**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <message-component></message-component>
    <header></header>
    <leftbar></leftbar>
    <body></body>
</div>
```

2. In the `body` component, I am using `ui-view` to render my component based on the current route.

At one time, three components are usually present : `header`, `leftbar` and `body`. I am using `ng-if` directive in my `leftbar` component in which I am calling a function.

**`leftbar.html`**

```
<li ng-if="leftbar.hasPermission('FOO')">
    <a ui-sref="foo">
        <span>Demo Page</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**`leftbar.controller`**

```
class LeftbarController {
    constructor() {}

    hasPermission(name) {
        return user[name];
    }
}
```

It basically shows the `<li>` if the user has a permission named "FOO".
Now, simultaneously my `body` component is also visible to the user and there is an input field present inside that, so whenever I write something in that field `hasPermission` method also gets called which is present in a different component.

So what can be the issue here? Why scopes are behaving like this ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem you are having, can you elaborate on the unexpected behavior and add the code from your `body` component ? Also, why is your `hasPermission` method not returning a boolean as it should ?

Comment: The actual issue is that whenever anything in the model(this) of any component changes, ngIf expression present in any other component also gets evaluate again.

Comment: Well yeah, that is how the digest cycle of AngularJS works, any change triggers a re-check of all rendered components.

Comment: Is it. well, I didn't know that. Thanks.
So, what can I do to avoid this? Should I use one time binding operator (::)

Comment: No, you need to make sure that the changes in other components of your application do not affect the behavior of the other component that you do not want to change. This way, no matter how many digest cycles are triggers, the re-evaluation of your directives does not yield different results.

Comment: How can I make sure that change in one component does not affect another one. Can you please elaborate the solution little bit.

Comment: I do not have enough information to do that, you need to add the code from the component that is being changed, the component that causes the change, the expected result that should not change and the changed result that you are getting.